# Computer boots to fast to see/read POST screen

Tags: boot, bios

I have a new HP ProDesk 400 G1 SFF desktop computer. When I start-up the computer, I get the screen where all the options are. (I believe it's called the POST screen, it's used for entering modules such as the BIOS or the boot menu.

[image]

My problem is, the computer boots up so fast that i can't even read or barely see what the screen says.

Is there a way I can make this screen last longer?

Comment: Is this running windows 8? Might be using fastboot, or a *really wierd* 2 key combo to get in.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Nope, this is running Windows 7 Proffesional (64bit). I can get into the BIOS though, i just have to know the key. The problem is that this screen won't last any longer then a second (or less)

Comment: You can try the PAUSE-Key to freeze the screen, <ESC> to continue.

Comment: @Milde It's a great solution, but i really prefer to modify a setting in the BIOS for this screen to last longer :)

Comment: I presume you had to use a high speed camera to capture that frame with the HP logo. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter the BIOS. F10 on your model and go to the Advanced tab you will see Power On Options. This will enable you to modify your post settings. The two that will probably be most useful to you are POST Mode (QuickBoot, FullBoot, CLear Memory and FullBoot Every x Days) and POST Delay.
With these settings you should be able to configure your boot up to display the POST Screen.

Comment: This did it, thank you. Is there a difference between QuickBoot and Fullboot though?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Default keys generally to enter BIOS are either Del on the numeric pad if available, F1 or F2. Usually if I have to enter the bios i press the power button then start tapping the keys mentioned immediately.

Once you are in the BIOS go to the Boot or Advanced options section and turn fast boot off this will disable the advertising logo and show you whats actually happening as your computer boots up. Once done, press F10 or go to exit and save the changes and restart, this time you should be met with a load of script on the screen informing you on the loading process and allowing you more time to get access to the BIOS.

Comment: This does not begin to answer the question asked.  Please explain in detail how this begins to answer the question "*Is there a way I can make this screen last longer*"?